# Can I use a for loop to check for variables in class and return different answer based on info like age or gender?

Tags: python, class, for-loop

I'm working through Eric Matthe's book and wanted to try a few extra things with for loops to see if I could get them to work for problem 9-3. Here is his code for the solution (for reference):

https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc/solutions/chapter_9.html#9-3-users

What I want to do is add in some extra code that will check if a user is male or female and give them a different response based on that. Am I going about it the right way by using a for loop?

```
class User:
def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, gender):
    self.first_name = first_name.title()
    self.last_name = last_name.title()
    self.age = age
    self.gender = gender.title()

def user_info(self):
    print(f"\nInformation available on USER: "
          f"\nFirst name: \t{self.first_name}"
          f"\nSecond name: \t{self.last_name}"
          f"\nAge: \t\t{self.age}"
          f"\nGender: \t{self.gender}")

def user_greeting(self):
    for gender in self.gender:
        if gender == 'Male':
            print("hello sir")
```

I edited the code to include the suggestion below but now I still get no output:

```
class User:
def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, gender):
    self.first_name = first_name.title()
    self.last_name = last_name.title()
    self.age = age
    self.gender = gender.title()

def user_info(self):
    print(f"\nInformation available on USER: "
          f"\nFirst name: \t{self.first_name}"
          f"\nSecond name: \t{self.last_name}"
          f"\nAge: \t\t{self.age}"
          f"\nGender: \t{self.gender}")

def user_greeting(self):
    if self.gender == 'male':
        print("hello sir")
```

Comment: if user can't have more than one gender, for loop is not needed. `if self.gender == 'Male':`

Comment: You have a class definition. You are missing the code you use to to create the instance and call the `user_greeting` method.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you need a loop. As your code is written, each instance of the class `User` will have only one gender of type string. That way, you can simply use an `if`. Thus, the code of the function `user_greeting` would be the following:

```py
def user_greeting(self):
    if self.gender == 'Male':
        print("hello sir")
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried updating that but I still get no output

Comment: Maybe is a typo: `'male'` instead of `'Male'`. If it still not work, please add the code where you create the instance. Another thing that you can do is to print the value of the `gender` attribute to see if it is correctly set.